# Catching Eloquent Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I perform various eloquent statements throughout my app. eg:

```
User::find($id)->update($data);
```

Or:

```
User::create($data);
```

Or:

```
User::paginate(10);
```

I presume the best way to tackle potential errors is to use try/catch? If so, what should I be catching for eloquent errors?

Comment: I think, eloquent is quite stable (if defined properly) and a collection is returned. So most of the the it is enough to use simple if condition. I thinke there is a modelNotFound Exception.

Comment: Foreign key exceptions can be handled in controllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `findOrFail()` method which will be helpful in some situations. But what kind of errors at runtime do you expect from `paginate()`, `update()`, `create()`?

During development Laravel will throw an exception when something is wrong with your model, like `MassAssignmentException` when some property you're trying to update is missing in `$fillable`.

Comment: Perhaps user is trying to add/update fields that do not exist in the database?

Comment: @panthro this kind of errors should be fixed during development (mass assignment will help you). You don't want to handle with with `try/catch` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! So what sort of errors should be handled at runtime? Regarding eloquent/database.